# Output field with double quotes in twig

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

We have a field, `field_text`, that we are displaying on the `Basic Page` content type. It needs to display with double quotes `"` using `twig` template. We tried the following below, but it is displaying without the `"` in the beginning and end.

**How can we display the `field_text` with double quotes (`"`) in `twig`?**

What we tried:

**node--page--full.html.twig**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {# None of the following worked #}
  "name" : {{ content.field_text.0 }}
  "name" : {{ '\"' ~ content.field_text.0 ~ '\"' }}
  "name" : {{ '\"' }} {{ content.field_text.0 ~ '\"' }} {{ '\"' }}
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't `"{{ }}"` work?

Comment: @4k4 when i do `"{{ content.field_text.0 }}"`, it results in `""` (an empty value)

Comment: Then the quotes are working, but the field variable is empty or non-existent. Twig doesn't throw errors for misspelled variable names, it silently returns NULL.

Comment: @4k4 it was indeed misspelled variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the value of the field and then concatenated with `"` like the second way:
I tested it with the following:

```
"name" : {{ content.field_text_test.0['#context']['value'] }} <br>
"name" : {{ '\"' ~ content.field_text_test.0['#context']['value'] ~ '\"' }} <br>
"name" : {{ '\"' }} {{ content.field_text_test.0['#context']['value'] ~ '\"' }} {{ '\"' }}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: it was the fact that i misspelled the name. i was missing a letter and it caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you saved my life, too :-)

you also have this double double quote problem, when setting up an inline svg in inline css in a twig template.

it finally works! thank you! :-)

```php
{# in twig template for a block type #}

{% set style_begin =
  "background-image:url("
  ~ '\"'
  ~ "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' class='h-6 w-6' fill='none' viewBox='0 0 24 24' stroke='%2386bbd8'><path stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' "
%}
{% set style_end = '/%3E%3C/svg%3E'
  ~ '\"'
  ~ ');'
%}

{% set fragment = content.field_block_bg_right_svg.0 %}

{# the "fragment" is from a text field in drupal that
   contains the actual svg paths from heroicons.com
   for example:
   d="M15 13l-3 3m0 0l-3-3m3 3V8m0 13a9 9 0 110-18 9 9 0 010 18z"
   this makes it a little easier for content-authors to choose
   their desired svg-background for this block...
#}

<div class="bg-brand4-900 bg-no-repeat bg-right bg-contain"
    style="{{ style_begin }} {{ fragment }} {{ style_end }}">
```